# Will a Logitech K750 keyboard work?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, compatibility

Is the [Logitech K750](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/k750-keyboard?wt.mc_id=global_pr-k750_redirect_112010) working in Ubuntu 10.10, Maverick Meerkat?

Comment: It uses the logitech unified wireless receiver. So the questions are: 1. Does the logitech unified receiver work with meerkat?
2. Does the logitech unified receiver work with this keyboard when running meerkat? Or are there special configurations required to get all the special keys (if any) to work?

Comment: Yes, It works allright when my OS (Ubuntu 11.04) is up. There's only one thing: when booting and going into the GRUB2 bootloader, I can't select options by using the arrow keys, nor can I use the 'e' for editing. Especially annoying if one has a second OS to choose from. Does anyone has a solution for this flaw?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both my keyboard and mouse both use the wireless receiver and they both worked with NO fiddling at all.........Work perfect (mx 3200 Lazer)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works with 10.10 I have one and there is no problem with it in Ubuntu 10.10.
Fantastic keyboard!

The FN keys works from default, no need to do anything, only thing you won't get is the lux meter app, as it is Windows only, but im sure it's only a matter of time before we can find a usermade app for it.

There is nothing not to like on this keyboard, best I ever used for sure.

//Casper Nilsson

Answer (score 2):

The keyword works like a charm, the only minor downside is that Logitech does not offer a linux version of their solarapp.

Answer (score 1):

Works great on 12.04 and 12.10.